# Why a ToList embedded in a WHERE clause behaves differently than a ToList executed outside of the query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I call this:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var yy = db.Products.Select(xx => xx.Id);
    var items = db.Products.Where(p => yy.ToList().Contains(p.Id));
}
```

(please note the `ToList` in the Where)
the generated script is

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent1].[Id]
)
```

and when I call this:

```
  var yy = db.Products.Select(xx => xx.Id).ToList();
  var items = db.Products.Where(p => yy.Contains(p.Id));
```

(the `ToList` pulled out of the lambda)
then the generated script is

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Price] AS [Price], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

Comment: Seems legit. What do you think is strange about it?

Comment: What is Diffrent between : var yy = db.Products.Select(xx => xx.Id); yy.ToList() and  db.Products.Select(xx => xx.Id).ToList();

Comment: @M.Azad: the difference is in the kind of lambda processing. The first one   creates you a `yy` query (IQueryable<Products>) and you are calling a ToList on it == immediate execution. The second one you now written in comments is EXACTLY the same. The THIRD one you didn't notice is: `db.Foobar.Where(  f = > db.Products.Where(...).ToList() ) `. Here the ToList is **not executed**. More, no part of that line is really executed. It, along with whole expression `f = > db.Products.Where(...).ToList()` is taken as `Expression<Func<Foobar,bool>>` and is translated into Where predicate for Foobar set.

Comment: The goal is to get a SQL query. The engine inspects each clause, sees the `f = > db.Products.Where(...).ToList()` expression and tries to generate a sql-where from it. It notices that there is a "query" inside, and generates such a subquery. The misleading point is that qhen you are not used to the way LINQ works, you may think that `f = > db.Products.Where(...).ToList()` actually tries to execute the `db.Products.Where(...).ToList()` part for each or for some Foobars. That would be absolutely correct for LINQ-to-Objects, but that's not necessary for LINQ-to-SQL, LINQ-to-EF and etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In second example, LINQ extension method `ToList()` **executes the query immediatelly** and returns you a List of results.  Therefore, in the second line, there is a **second, independent** query that takes the List of the previous results. That's why you observe `IN` operator.

So, in the 2nd example, you've got a one query on DB, then list of INTs flies back to your code, then second query runs on DB.

In the first example, the first line creates a query, but does not execute it yet. Then in the second line, the original query from first line is "wrapped" in another query. And this is exactly what you see in resulting SQL code: an outer query (from-the-second-line) with subquery (inner, original, from-the-first-line).

Here, in first example, you've got just one query running on the DB. You don't have a "intermediate preview" of the IDs affected. The `ToList()` that is present in the second query is in fact all contained in lambda expression of the where clause (thanks to haim770 for pointing it out) and **your LINQ provider** (1) is smart enough to notice that the left-side of the ToList is also a query object so it skips the ToList and concatenates the queries. It's sometimes/often better to have it all in one query, as the DB can sometimes optimize it better, and that's one query instead of two -- that counts if your connection is slow, or if you have to repeat it hundreds of times. Removing the number of roundtrips counts.

Everything is normal. Think about it and get used to it, that's how LINQ/IQueryable and similar APIs are designed to be: collect the query, allow the programmer to build it up, and execute it only if really needed.

(1) please note that I deliberately say "your LINQ provider". This is not a must. LINQ provider get all the parts of the query (expressions) and analyzes them and translates to SQL-or-whatever-else. A different provider (i.e. to different DB engine, to XML, to objects, etc) may do it differently, and may for example execute the ToList as separate query. The same stands for "embedding queries" and the same stands for almost all in LINQ.. Some provider may even throw you a "NotSupported" when you try to use WHERE (i.e too complex) or a JOIN (just because of bad mood) clause. Seriously.

Comment: The crucial part here is that since the `ToList()` call is encapsulated within an `Expression`, EF is able to ignore it and only extract the "is contains" logic from it.

Comment: @haim770: ah yes, I overlooked that one. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `.ToList()` call materializes a LinQ statement. You can read about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx), it's called deferred execution.

In your first statement, you leave the materializing to the database, so it can form a proper join because it knows where the values came from or rather *will* come from.

Your second try materializes the values to your application and then *sends the actual values* to the database. So the database does not know it's a join, it just sees numbers coming in.

Comment: `you leave the materializing to the database` - Not to the database. To the  LINQ provider which is (in this example) generating the SQL. The DB does not see the "first query" or "materializing" here at all. It's some smart optimization in the provider. A little bit misleading, as ToList/ToArray/ToEnumerable are traditionally meant to execute it immediatelly, so my first blind guess would be that I and II would result in the same query.